# Can I mimic the "open" action in QGIS with python and manipulate the field content used for the action?

Tags: qgis, python, actions

I am using QGIS actions (type: "open") to link ECM searches to objects on the map.

The basic syntax is very simple:

```
protocol://searchterm1=[%"field1"%]&searchterm2=[%"field2"%]
```

However, some fields used for the search contain spaces and the system can't handle them. For example, "York" works. "South Hampshire" however doesn't.

Can I somehow mimic the open action with python, and use it to manipulate the value from the field? Like picking the first word before a space and using only that for the search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I might as well post the answer I came up with here:

```
from os import startfile

baseurl = http://www.google.com/
someattribute = '[% "attributefield1" %]'
someattributesplit = someattribute.partition(' ')[0] #get word before first space
path = baseurl+someattributesplit

startfile(path)
```